# How to add vertical line on a complete wordPress page?

Tags: css, wordpress, line, elementor

I'm using Flatsome theme on wordpress and need to draw vertical lines on three sides (left center right) on a complete home page. you can see as a reference site (https://pelicula.qodeinteractive.com/) where vertical line are implemented on-page. These vertical lines are implemented from top to end and I need the same in my design.

Is there any plugin that can help?
What approach should I consider?
Any suggestion would be appreciated

(https://pelicula.qodeinteractive.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with simple htmtl elements and css.
Just add three divs at the main website files (or better the header.php) of your child theme (more information: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
and then apply the following css to it.

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1px;
  position: fixed;
}

#one {
  background: blue;
  left: 20%;
}

#two {
  background: green;
  left: 50%;
}

#three {
  background: orange;
  right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: Just incase OP doesn't know much about HTML/CSS as they are asking about a plugin to do a simple HTML/CSS thing.  I'd recommend to them to assign a class to the lines and not just use `div` in the CSS. So like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zfnu1okg/2/

Comment: You're right. My answer is only for people which have at least a little experience in working with child themes in wordpress and HTML/CSS.

Comment: This work with simple page but how can I do it with elementor?

Comment: This works also with elementor. As stated above, add the divs to the header.php file in `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/header.php` and add the css to custom css.